# Prevent list from being wrapped by XML-element

Tags: list, nested, jaxb, eclipselink

Example code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    private long userid;
    private IPerson person; 
}
```

Produces this output:

```
<user>
    <person>
        <firstname />
        <lastname />
    </person>
</user>
```

I'd like to prevent the 'person'-element from being generated, so that the person-fields will be directly included in the 'user'-element, like this:

```
<user>
    <firstname />
    <lastname />
</user>
```

Can JAXB/EclipseLink be configured to produce this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s `@XmlPath` extension to map this use case:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    private long userid;

    @XmlPath(".")
    private IPerson person; 
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html